# Code snippet plugin not working correctly with Windows live writer and Wordpress

Tags: plugins, code

Downloaded the [The Live Writer Source Code Plug-in For WordPress.com Blogs](http://richhewlett.com/wlwsourcecodeplugin/). The preview looks good but the published version looks really messed up. Could anybody let me know what could be the fix.

In the preview in template of Code snippet plugin():-
[image]

After publish :-
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just looked around and all I needed to do to [disable HTML encoding](http://richhewlett.com/2012/09/19/live-writer-syntax-highlighting-plug-in-minor-update/).